# Eclipse not compiling new Android code

Tags: android

For some reason, after I build my Android project in Eclipse, it is not giving me any errors, but none of my updates are being compiled.

I've tried both running my app in the emulator, and installing the apk on my phone.  It still only compiles the old version of my app, not the new one.  I've tried deleting the apk in the bin folder manually before recompiling it, and cleaning the project.

The previous thing that occurred was, my certificate expired, so I deleted the old certificate file.

I do not see any errors in the error log or the console.  I'm still pretty new to all this.

Comment: Was `Project->Clean` any help?

Comment: No, nothing works.  I don't even know where it's getting the old stuff that I've totally changed, yet it still compiles this old stuff.

Comment: Why not uninstall the app from your phone, and then try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse can mess up sometimes. It would be worth closing Eclipse and rebooting your PC.

Edit: Try reconfiguring your Run Configuration by deleting it and recreating it

Comment: I rebooted but no luck.  I've never seen such a thing... I changed a text field to "Summary" that said "Description" yet the apk still says "Description".  Where is this old stuff coming from?  It's totally messed up.

Comment: What must be happening is that you are editing one program, and Eclipse runs another. Delete your run configuration and reconfigure it. This will make sure you're running what you're editing. Go to Run > Run Configurations

Comment: I also deleted the files in the gen folder.  A combination of all this seemed to be what fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has been driving me nuts recently. I recently migrated from XP to Windows 7, and thought it was a quirk of Eclipse running in XP, but it is still happening, i.e. any changes made, I had to compile twice to get the current version.

For some reason, the solution for me is to make sure the changes are saved before compiling. If you don't save, and do so on the Dialog that pops up when you compile/run, you have to go again. Don't know why this is, maybe I am missing something, it worked fine a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse didn't export the most recent updates for my app.
What worked for me:

1. In terminal (being in the work folder):
   cordova build android
2. In Eclipse: Clean project.
3. Refresh
4. Export app